# Cocoa podspec and path for dependency

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, podspec

how can I specify in podspec a local path for an dependency ?

like : *s.dependency 'MyLibrary', :path => '../MyLibrary'*

thanks

Comment: the first solution is not for a podspec file, the second not work for me, apparently cannot specify a path for the dependency in a podspec file :(

Comment: Okay, did you see the official guide? :) https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html

Comment: @Danilo Did it solved your error ?

Comment: @Loegic no, cannot specify a path for dependencies :(

Comment: @Danilo, answer updated !

Comment: Did you solve your issue ?

Comment: Hi @Loegic, no but I use the path declaration directly on podspec :
s.subspec 'library' do |ss| ss.source_files = '../path/library/**/.{h,m}' ss.resource = '../path/library/**/*.xib' end... thanks for your time.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should use the `:path` keyword in your `Podfile` :

```
pod 'AFNetworking', :path => '~/Documents/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.podspec'
```

Tips: If you don't know the path, you can drag & drop the file in your `Podfile` and it will display it.

EDIT

I did not understand correctly what the OP was asking for, here is the correct answer:

1. Put the local dependency inside your pod's folder root directory,
2. In your Podspec file, just add `s.ios.dependency 'YourPodName/YourPodDependencyFolder'`

After that, create a subspace like so:

```
s.subspec 'YourPodName' do |ss|
ss.source_files = 'YourPodName/**/*.{h,m}'
end
```

Comment: I use the second way, but the path of source_files are preceded by the ".. /"

Comment: Remove the ../ in that case. If you read correctly, you have to place the source file of the dependency in the root folder of the pod

Comment: what is this `s.ios.dependency 'YourPodName/YourPodDependencyFolder'` meaned by ?. can you elaborate?

Comment: :local dependency was removed from podspec a long time ago, you need to publish cocoapod to mention it as a depedency in another podspec.

Comment: What do you mean `YourPodDependencyFolder`?

Comment: If you cannot, or prefer not to, put the local dependency inside the pod folder's root directory, you can use `s.prepare_command` to run `ln -s` command that will create symlink of the local dependency inside the pod folder.

Answer (score 2):

I can't put the other libraries in the root of my library, these are inside the parent because are shared with other project, but unfortunately without use the pods, and I'm trying to use the pods for all, and I already configured the podspec for all libraries.

I'm trying to do something like this written below, but do not appear to work:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name                  = 'MyLibrary'
    s.platform              = 'ios'
    s.ios.deployment_target = '7.1'
    s.source_files          = 'Classes/**/.{h,m}'
    s.resource              = 'Classes/resources/*.*'
    s.requires_arc          = true
    s.dependency 'AFNetworking'
    s.dependency 'SharedLib'

    s.subspec 'SharedLib' do |ss|
        ss.source_files         = '../SharedLib/Classes/**/*.{h,m}'
        s.resource              = '../SharedLib/Classes/resources/*.*'
        ss.ios.framework        = 'AVFoundation'
    end
end
```

thanks for all.

Comment: @Danilo... how do you set local path in source of the pod spec.. I tried with the below and it installed right files in my project however when I am trying to update in files in pod spec, its not updating in example project!!

 s.source           = {  :path => ".", :tag => s.version.to_s }

Comment: @Saty I don't longer use that system, I use saving the library in svn addr http: //your-ip/lib-name/trunk/1.0.0 and add spec in podfile like this: pod 'lib-name', :svn => "http: //your-ip/lib-name/trunk/1.0.0".

Comment: the path you have given here is the path in podfile.. I want to know pod spec file details when you create the cocoapod....

Comment: @Saty i use this: s.source = { :svn => 'http: //my-svn-server/MyLib/trunk/1.0.0' } (remove the space after http:)

Comment: Im not able to integrate my local framework with pod project.