# Is it possible to add a local dependency to .podspec file?

Tags: cocoapods, dependency-management

I'm using cocoapods now I would like to add a local pod dependency in my project, something like:

```
s.dependency = 'my pod', :path => ''
```

but I think is not possibile, some ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cocoa podspec and path for dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32581986/cocoa-podspec-and-path-for-dependency)

Answer (score 60):

I have faced with the same issue and after lot of googling and asking on the CocoaPods GitHub I have finally found the suitable answer.

It's not possible to set a local pod as a dependency, but it's possible to set a pod's source for a specific Podfile, which will work the same way.

E.g., in your podspec, you still have ()

```
s.dependency = 'my pod', '~> 1.0' # or whatever version you have
```

Then in your Example/demo/test project's Podfile:

```
pod 'my pod', :path => '/path/to/the/local/my_pod'
```

Then just run `pod install` and you will see both pods as a Development pods.

This way is very useful when you're developing 2 pods (one of which is dependend on the other) simultaneously, yet for release you will still have to publish your pod to the repo (either CocoaPods or a private repo).

Comment: Validation on your podspec fails when doing this. `(Unable to find a specification for 'yoga' depended upon by 'MyLib'`

Comment: @Tieme No need to run validation, it's just for developing/debugging a dependency pod.

Comment: So you remove the dependency before you submit?

Comment: @Tieme no, why? dependency is for a real pod. Just this approach allwos to install a local pod's version for that dependency via a project's Podfile. And for a Pod submit you're using a *.podspec, not a Podfile.

Answer (score 1):

Put the local dependency inside your pod's folder root directory,
In your Podspec file, just add s.ios.dependency 'YourRootPodName/YourPodDependencyFolder'
After that, create a subspace like so:

s.subspec 'YourRootPodName' do |ss|
ss.source_files = 'YourRootPodName/**/*.{h,m}'
end

as in this answer [Cocoa podspec and path for dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32581986/cocoa-podspec-and-path-for-dependency/32588068?s=6|20.9889#32588068)