# Flutter - Plugin, how dependency a ios local pod

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I write a Flutter plugin, and in the plugin's ios folder. There is a .podspec file. This file shown below:

```
# To learn more about a Podspec see http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html
#

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'qr_code_scanner'
  s.version          = '0.0.2'
  s.summary          = 'QR Code Scanner for flutter.'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
A new Flutter project.
                       DESC
  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/juliuscanute/qr_code_scanner'
  s.license          = { :file => '../LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Your Company' => 'juliuscanute[*]touchcapture.net' }
  s.source           = { :path => '.' }
  s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*'
  s.public_header_files = 'Classes/**/*.h'
  s.dependency 'Flutter'
  s.dependency 'how to dependency a local library'   //here
  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0' 
  s.swift_version = '4.0'
end
```

As we all know, if I want dependency a pod library. I can write:

```
s.dependency 'JSONModel'
```

but now, I download the JSONModel, and do some changes, then generate local pod. so the question is how to dependency a local modified "JSONModel" pod?

Comment: The answer by norlin should help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46052798/is-it-possible-to-add-a-local-dependency-to-podspec-file

Comment: @vrachlin I checked the answer, but still do not how to do

Comment: @zhouxinle Did you manage to figure out how to add a local pod?

Comment: @CatalinMorosan see the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can dependcy your own framework like this: write in plugin's podspec file:

```
  s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'Frameworks/TencentLBS.framework'
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'TencentLBS.framework'
```