# Cannot find generated -Swift.h file from local pod

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, react-native

I am creating a Turbo Module for React Native. The TM depends on another pod that I have created locally. I'm getting a compilation error stating that my generated `-Swift.h` header file is missing.

Heres the setup:

I have a local pod (lets call it "MyLocalPod") that is written in Swift. It is intended to use this pod with Objective-C code from my Turbo Module, so I have placed `@objc` attributes to the relevant public code in the pod. I have also updated some `struct`s to be `class` objects that extends `NSObject` as well.

I have a React Native Turbo Module package setup with an example RN project included. The TM package's podspec uses the above local pod like so:

`s.dependency "MyLocalPod"`

Now I know you cannot add a local development pod to a podspec file so I used a workaround from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49422999/10820594. My example app's `Podfile` is like the following:

`pod 'MyLocalPod', :path => '/Users/dev/Projects/MyLocalPod'`

In my Objective-C (.mm file) source code for the TM I import my local pod like:

`#import <MyLocalPod/MyLocalPod-Swift.h>`

But I always get a compilation error when I run `npm run ios` that says `fatal error: 'MyLocalPod/MyLocalPod-Swift.h' file not found`. The `MyLocalPod-Umbrella.h` file is found, but not the `-Swift.h` file.

I have tried a few things:

1. Cleaned the product build, manually deleted DerivedData, and deleted Pods folder and Podfile.lock before completely re-adding the TM, codegen, and `pod install` multiple times (and in different orders)
2. I manually built `MyLocalPod` before doing `pod install` in the example app
3. Found the generated `MyLocalPod-Swift.h` header file deep in DerivedData and added its path to `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` in XCode
4. Set `Defined Modules` to `YES` in `MyLocalPod`'s target's Build Settings

Each possible fix never found the generated `-Swift.h` file.