# How to resolve third party dependencies using relative path in Podfile

Tags: swift, cocoapods, podspec

I have a problem resolving third-party dependencies when I use the project path in Podfile.

For example, if I have a pod named `TestingPod` and
in the `TestingPod.podspec` I have defined dependencies to another pod.
For example `ChildPod`.

The `TestingPod.podspec` would look like:

```rb
spec.dependency 'ChildPod', '0.1'
```

And my application would have a `Podfile`:

```rb
target 'Test App' do
  use_frameworks!
  
  # Pods for Test App
  pod 'TestingPod', :path => 'path/to/TestingPod.podspec'
end
```

This way when I try to call `pod install` I get an error:

```
Unable to find a specification for `ChildPod(= 0.1)` depended upon by `TestingPod`
```

The thing that resolves the problem is to add manually dependency in `Podfile`:

```rb
target 'Test App' do
  use_frameworks!
  
  # Pods for Test App
  pod 'TestingPod', :path => 'path/to/TestingPod.podspec'
  pod 'ChildPod', :path => 'path/to/ChildPod.podspec'
end
```

But then I'm not sure what is the point of setting dependency in the `TestingPod.podspec` if I have manually to add the dependency in the `Podfile`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's because dependencies can't be local it seems. You can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46052798/is-it-possible-to-add-a-local-dependency-to-podspec-file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32581986/cocoa-podspec-and-path-for-dependency and other linked questions in comments/answers Some are old, but I don't think this has changed. There are some other workaround

Comment: Thanks @Larme for the comment and the links!