# In iOS Can we add public dependency in private pod?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, cocoapods, cocoapods-app

I'am working on private pod. everything is ok but I am unable to import my library inside the project.Its giving me error no module found.
But I'am able to import the dependencies that I'am using in pod such as Alamofire, Firebase.
Please Suggest me the solution.

Comment: If it's a "direct pod", you can. You can specify the URL for your private pod. See https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod the part "From a podspec in the root of a library repository." If it's a dependecy of your custom pod, it's harder, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70292706/how-to-resolve-third-party-dependencies-using-relative-path-in-podfile#comment124258014_70292706 I linked 2 questions with work around

Comment: Make sure you have proper passwordless access configured for the repo from which your pod is imported. But if you are saying that "module is not found", while `pod install` completes successfully, your problem is not on Podfile level, it's more about how you build your pod or its compatibility with your project. More details are needed to understand the issue though

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.